# GitHub, Xcode and organizational matters

Tags: github

My company is starting to use GitHub for source control. We have many development platforms, iOS, Android, Java, etc. I would think it would be best practice to segregate our repos so there are not 80 repos in one big list.

I have read that you can make a dir in git (hopefully you can do this on the web version of GitHub) and move the repository there. Others said that's what organizations are for.

Looking for ideas about how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use a separate repo for each project.

Worse than having 80 repos in one big list is having 80 projects in one big list. Thus making every developer pull all changes made to the entire codebase when he is only working on one project. 
This is what would happen if you were using a dir in git for each project.

Github organizations represent groups/projects/companies that are responsible for one or more repositories. Inside the organization you can have multiple repositories, e.g. one for the iOS, another with Android, backend, etc. But for git these repositories are completely independent.